# jQuery select by class and pass current element as parameter in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, mouseover, parameter-passing

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.classOne').mouseover(function(e) {  
        alert($(e).attr('id'));  
    });  
});
```

Now, I know that something is actually wrong with my code, what will be correct in order to get the result with the ID of the current `asp:LinkButton` that I hovered in the `alert()` message?
Thanks for all helpers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e is your event, not your element.  Your element is wrapped in this function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.classOne').mouseover(function(e) {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.classOne').mouseover(function() {
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of assumptions:

- The link button is rendered with the valid class 'classOne'
- The button is not added to the page collection via an AJAX callback
- the 'e' parameter actualy is an object of the event & not really the object of the HTML element

  (document).ready(function(){
           $('.classOne').bind('mouseover', function(){
             alert($(this).attr('id'));
           });
          });